# Problem with the presentation of data from the database on the html page in Django

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a problem creating something like this in the html file, of course based on the data from the database and using loop:

```
Cycle_title1
post_title1
post_title2
post_title3

Cycle_title2
post_title1
post_title2
post_title3
```

where post_title are post titles which was added to subsequent cycles

---

I tried do it in this way, but it return only one set of titles:

```py
#views

 cycles = Cycle.objects.filter(author=user)

    for cycle in cycles:
        c_post = Post.objects.filter(cycle__title__startswith=cycle.title)

 context = {
        'posts': posts,
        'user': user,
        'u_form': u_form,
        'p_form': p_form,
        'cycles': cycles,
        'c_post': c_post,
    }
    print(c_post)

    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)

#html

{% for cycle in cycles %}
          <h4>{{cycle.title}}</h4>
    {% for c in c_post %}
        <h5>{{ c.title }}</h5>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

---

```py
#my_models: 

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    content = MDTextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Cycle(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500, default="Brak opisu")
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    posts = models.ManyToManyField(Post)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you'll only get one set of posts, you keep resetting the `c_post` variable each time over the loop so you'll just end up with the one from the last iteration.

You shouldn't be doing this in the view at all. You should do it in the template. Plus, you shouldn't be doing that strange filtering on title__starts_with; you should just follow the relation.

```
{% for cycle in cycles %}
    <h4>{{cycle.title}}</h4>
    {% for c in cycle.posts.all %}
        <h5>{{ c.title }}</h5>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```